# XAML Layout is TextWrapping Nothing in WP7.5

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I've run into a bit of a strange problem with some XAML layout in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7.5. Basically, I'm creating a number of textboxes in a grid in a canvas, using my own bullet points. The issue is that the first bullet point (see below) has an extended textbox, for no apparent reason. It looks like it is TextWrapping no text. See the spacing below the first bullet point. You'll also notice this cuts off some text on the third bullet:

### INCORRECT LAYOUT:

[image: incorrect layout]

Here's the code for the `<Canvas/>` object that hosts all of the text and bullet points:

```
  <Canvas Canvas.Left="20.21" Canvas.Top="66" Width="775.96" Height="224.17">
    <Grid Canvas.Top="3.6" Canvas.Left="7.2" Width="762.06" Height="216.97">
      <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
          <TextBlock LineHeight="21.6" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="18">
            <Run Text="The Ribbon bar in PowerPoint 2007 and 2010 replaces the menu bar in previous versions. It is designed to provide quick access to the most common features used in PowerPoint." />
          </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 0 0 6">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="22.5" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" LineHeight="15.12" Foreground="#D80073" FontFamily="Wingdings" FontSize="12.6" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight">
              <Run Text="" />
            </TextBlock>
          </Grid>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" LineHeight="19.2" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontFamily="Segoe WP">
            <Run Text="The " FontSize="16" /><Run Text="R" FontSize="16" /><Run Text="ibbon is " FontSize="16" /><Run Text="made up of various tabs that provide a fast way of performing tasks. For example, if you need to insert a picture, you click the " FontSize="16" /><Run Text="Insert" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" /><Run Text=" tab and then picture. If you need to create an animation, you click on the " FontSize="16" /><Run Text="Animations" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" /><Run Text=" tab and then, with any object selected, simply select the animation you prefer." FontSize="16" />
          </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="0 0 0 6">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="22.5" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" LineHeight="15.12" Foreground="#D80073" FontFamily="Wingdings" FontSize="12.6" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight">
              <Run Text="" />
            </TextBlock>
          </Grid>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" LineHeight="19.2" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontFamily="Segoe WP">
            <Run Text="Some " FontSize="16" /><Run Text="R" FontSize="16" /><Run Text="ibbon " FontSize="16" /><Run Text="bars are contextual – meaning they only appear when you’ve selected the corresponding object. The Drawing (shape), Picture (image) and Table (table) tabs become available and highlighted when you’ve selected those objects." FontSize="16" />
          </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="0 0 0 6">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="22.5" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" LineHeight="15.12" Foreground="#D80073" FontFamily="Wingdings" FontSize="12.6" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight">
              <Run Text="" />
            </TextBlock>
          </Grid>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" LineHeight="19.2" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontFamily="Segoe WP">
            <Run Text="Also" FontSize="16" /><Run Text=", when your PowerPoint application is resized, the Ribbon will minimize or display buttons. This means that the command is still available, but it may look and act slightly different" FontSize="16" /><Run Text="." FontSize="16" />
          </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Canvas>
```

A full copy of the XAML page (UserControl) and pictures is on [DropBox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16442383/Slide2.zip).

I've found two manual ways to fix this:

1. From the first bullet text, remove any three letters. This causes
   the bottom spacing to be removed. This is a bit weird though as the
   text in line #2 of the first bullet extends to the width of the grid
   and in the 3rd one doesn't come as close, so it doesn't make sense
   why this would "fix" the issue.
2. Put a `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` on the *second row* in the
   first grid instead of `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />`. This is
   unpredictable though - if I set it to `*` for other rowes, it
   mis-sizes again. I'm doing this coding from automation, so I won't
   be able to predict a problematic row unless I know exactly what the
   problem may be in advance in order to set it as `*` instead of
   `Auto`.

This is what it looks like if it is laid out correctly (by using #2 above):

### CORRECT LAYOUT

[image: correct layou]

Does anyone know what exactly is wrong here with this "fake text wrapping of nothing" and how to fix / predict it?

Comment: Just curious, where did you get these beautiful nokia phone images? :)

Comment: @Xin: You can get them from here: http://wp7emuskinswitcher.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need this `Canvas` to wrap the `Grid`.

```
<Canvas Canvas.Left="20.21" Canvas.Top="66" Width="775.96" Height="224.17">
```

I downloaded your file and removed this `Canvas`, also changed the inner `Grid`'s attributes to be something like this,

```
<Grid Canvas.Top="70" Canvas.Left="27" MaxWidth="762.06">
```

You can see I removed the `Height` and this fixed your second issue. Initilally the `Grid` wasn't long enough to display all the text.

Another change I made was replaced `Width` with `MaxWidth`, this way the `Width` is now auto sized, if you recomplie your project you will see the word `prefer.` now goes to the second line and fills the gap perfectly.

I think the real problem is once you give `TextBlock` a fixed `Width`, first it thinks the word `prefer.` needs to go to the next line but because the `Width` is a fixed value it somehow still squeezes it at the end of the line. To avoid this, you probably want to make the `Width` auto-sized.

I might be wrong but hope this could be any of help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the combination of all these fixed values causes the wrapping to be strange. I have a suggestion which solves the wrapping issue while conserving most of these values. The `DockPanel` ([described and downloadable here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Using-DockPanel-in-WP7)) does the job quite well.

I use one `DockPanel` for each combination of bullet point and text replacing the two `Grid`s used before:

```
<Canvas Canvas.Left="20.21" Canvas.Top="66" Width="775.96" Height="224.17">
    <Grid Canvas.Top="3.6" Canvas.Left="7.2" Width="762.06" Height="216.97">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBlock LineHeight="21.6" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="18">
                    <Run Text="The Ribbon bar in PowerPoint 2007 and 2010 replaces the menu bar in previous versions. It is designed to provide quick access to the most common features used in PowerPoint." />
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <my:DockPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dockPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 0 0 6">
                <TextBlock Width="22.5" LineHeight="15.12" Foreground="#D80073" FontFamily="Wingdings" FontSize="12.6" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight">
                    <Run Text="" />
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock LineHeight="19.2" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontFamily="Segoe WP">
                    <Run Text="The " FontSize="16" /><Run Text="R" FontSize="16" /><Run Text="ibbon is " FontSize="16" /><Run Text="made up of various tabs that provide a fast way of performing tasks. For example, if you need to insert a picture, you click the " FontSize="16" /><Run Text="Insert" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" /><Run Text=" tab and then picture. If you need to create an animation, you click on the " FontSize="16" /><Run Text="Animations" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" /><Run Text=" tab and then, with any object selected, simply select the animation you prefer." FontSize="16" />
                </TextBlock>
            </my:DockPanel>
            <my:DockPanel Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dockPanel2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 0 0 6">
                <TextBlock Width="22.5" LineHeight="15.12" Foreground="#D80073" FontFamily="Wingdings" FontSize="12.6" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight">
                    <Run Text="" />
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock LineHeight="19.2" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontFamily="Segoe WP">
                    <Run Text="Some " FontSize="16" /><Run Text="R" FontSize="16" /><Run Text="ibbon " FontSize="16" /><Run Text="bars are contextual – meaning they only appear when you've selected the corresponding object. The Drawing (shape), Picture (image) and Table (table) tabs become available and highlighted when you've selected those objects." FontSize="16" />
                </TextBlock>
            </my:DockPanel>
            <my:DockPanel Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dockPanel3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 0 0 6">
                <TextBlock Width="22.5" LineHeight="15.12" Foreground="#D80073" FontFamily="Wingdings" FontSize="12.6" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight">
                    <Run Text="" />
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" LineHeight="19.2" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontFamily="Segoe WP">
                    <Run Text="Also" FontSize="16" /><Run Text=", when your PowerPoint application is resized, the Ribbon will minimize or display buttons. This means that the command is still available, but it may look and act slightly different" FontSize="16" /><Run Text="." FontSize="16" />
                </TextBlock>
            </my:DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

This panel might also be well suited for other parts of your layout.